# Как сделать таблицу товаров Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как реализовать вот такой, табличный вид вывода товаров на сайте [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Убери ссылку и покажи скришот, если не хочешь что бы удалили вопрос.

Comment: окееееееееееееееееей

Comment: get_products() и понеслась

Comment: Если интересует реализация на сайте. то есть масса плагинов https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/table+products/

Comment: Плагины сильно ограничены по функционалу.